# Site com barra invertida em localhost

Tags: php

Baixei o site do server e coloquei para rodar em localhost. Porém, ele não está fazendo a chamada dos arquivos corretamente. Primeiro, ele chama "http://localhost" e depois o caminho da pasta, com barra invertida.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Há uma regra definida para chamar todos os arquivos:

```
<?php
define("MY_BASE_DIR", 'C:');
define("SITE_PATH", __DIR__ . '/');
define("SITE_VIRTUAL_DIR", str_replace($_SERVER["DOCUMENT_ROOT"], "", SITE_PATH));
define("ENGINE_PATH", SITE_PATH.'includes/fw/'); // caminho pro FW
define("CMS_ENGINE_PATH", SITE_PATH.'includes/cms/cms.php');
```

Tentei mudar essa regra, mas sem sucesso.

Essa configuração de barra invertida é algum trecho nos arquivos do código que tem quer se modificada ou é configuração do meu servidor local (estou usando o WampServer)?

**-----------------------------   UPDATE ------------------------------**

Esse é o arquivo que dá caminho para os arquivos:

```
public function Setup()
{
    parent::Setup();

    if (\Browser::Obsolet())
    {
        $this->context->UpdateYourBrowser();
    }

    if(!defined("ADMIN_DIR")){
        define("ADMIN_DIR", dirname($_SERVER["SCRIPT_NAME"]) . "/");
        define("ADMIN_URL", DOMAIN . ADMIN_DIR );
    }

    if(!defined("ADMIN_PATH"))
    {
        throw new \Exception("Para acessar um módulo do backend você precisa esta no diretorio do admin/");
    }

    // configura a sessao do usuario
    $this->context->set("USER.SESSION", $this->context->get("USER.SESSION") . ADMIN_PATH . "_ADMIN");

    // configura o template do ADMIN
    // checa se o usuario especificou algum caminho para o template do ADMIN
    $templatePath = $this->context->get("CMS.ADMIN.TEMPLATE_PATH");
    if(!$templatePath){
        $templatePath = ADMIN_PATH;
    }
    $this->context->setTemplatePath($templatePath); //diretorio raiz de templates?
    $this->context->setTemplate($this->context->get('CMS.ADMIN.TEMPLATE')); // seta o template configurado no config.php

    // checa se o usuario especificou algum caminho para o template do ADMIN
    $templateUrl = $this->context->get("CMS.ADMIN.TEMPLATE_URL");
    if(!$templateUrl){
        $templateUrl = ADMIN_DIR; // URI do admin: http://localhost/admin/
    }
    if(!defined("TEMPLATE_URL"))
        define("TEMPLATE_URL", $templateUrl . $this->context->TemplateDir() . $this->context->getTemplate() . "/");
}
```

@Rafaelphp Os arquivos estão sendo chamados através do `TEMPLATE_URL`:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="<?php echo TEMPLATE_URL ?>static/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
```

Ainda estou tentando fazer com que ele chame de direto, mas sem sucesso.

Comment: Isso aí funcionava no linux? o que acontece é que a substitição não acontece.

Comment: O __DIR__ pega o diretório do arquivo atual, logo terá o caminho completo do Windows, dê uma olhada no array $_SERVER, ele contem algumas alternativas para setar o SITE_PATH. Só dar um `var_dump` nele. Acho que o $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'] deve te ajudar.

Comment: vc tem como postar o que tem no codigo fonte ex:
`<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="<?php echo $obj->script_path" />`

Comment: Atualizei a minha pergunta, por favor vejam se possível.

Answer (score 1):

Acredito que parte do problema esteja nesse trecho:

```
define("SITE_PATH", __DIR__ . '/');
define("SITE_VIRTUAL_DIR", str_replace($_SERVER["DOCUMENT_ROOT"], "", SITE_PATH));
```

O nome "SITE_VIRTUAL_DIR" sugere que deve ser o caminho virtual, mas está misturando com caminho físico.

Para entender melhor, caminho físico é algo assim `C:/www/site/`;

E caminho virtual é algo como `http://site/foo/`

Nos códigos que postou não é possível afirmar onde realmente está o erro pois o resultado final é montado nesse trecho

```
 if(!defined("TEMPLATE_URL"))
        define("TEMPLATE_URL", $templateUrl . $this->context->TemplateDir() . $this->context->getTemplate() . "/");
}
```

Um jeito prático de encontrar o problema é criar breakpoints nos locais mais óbvios e analisar os dados.

Sugestões de breakpoints:

Logo após `define("SITE_VIRTUAL_DIR", str_replace($_SERVER["DOCUMENT_ROOT"], "", SITE_PATH));`, adicione `echo SITE_VIRTUAL_DIR; exit;`

Se não estiver errado, vá para outro ponto mais lógico e faça outro breakpoint.

Obviamente, desabilite o breakpoint anterior para continuar a execução.

Logo após essa linha

```
define("TEMPLATE_URL", $templateUrl . $this->context->TemplateDir() . $this->context->getTemplate() . "/");
```

Adicione isso

```
echo TEMPLATE_URL.PHP_EOL.'<br>';
echo $templateUrl.PHP_EOL.'<br>';
echo $this->context->TemplateDir().PHP_EOL.'<br>';
echo $this->context->getTemplate().PHP_EOL.'<br>';
exit;
```

Tenho quase certeza que é nesse ponto que você terá uma idéia melhor da origem do problema. Pois saberá onde exatamente provém a parte que está montando errado.

Mas enfim, não garanto nada. São apenas observações lógicas. Apenas procure entender a lógica dos breakpoints para depurar o código e então aprender a corrigir os seus códigos.

Outra coisa mais óbvia ainda é, procure saber se não existe uma documentação desse sistema ou se não consegue consultar o autor do mesmo. Uma simples consulta pode ser melhor do que ficar lambendo código.

Pegunta relacionada (SO-en)https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38543229/site-with-wrong-call-on-localhost